# Java Basic GUI (Layout Error)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

So I am creating a game which contains 5x5 matrix of buttons, behind one of which is a hidden prize. I am done with the game, but I am having problems with the layout.

I have added the picture:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8q9Z.png

The one on the left side comes up when I run the program, and when I click the button the picture on the right side comes up.

The first `JFrame` looks very weird I mean it occupies the whole screen length wise, so I need to pack it to just display the button in a decent size.

The second one, I need the first row to display just the label,
and then onwards each row to contain 5 buttons.

I am quite sure I am using wrong layouts but I cant figure it out how to fix it. 
Below are the codes:

`MyJFrame` class code:

```
class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
JPanel panel2;

public MyJFrame() {
setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 7));

panel2 = new PanelJ2();

add(panel2);
JButton b = new JButton("Start the freaking game");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    panel2.setVisible(true);
    b.setVisible(false);
    PotLuck.random = (int)(Math.random() * 25 + 1);
  }
});
add(b);
setTitle( "This is a freaking game");
pack();
setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
}
}
```

`PanelJ2` code:

```
class PanelJ2 extends JPanel {
JButton[] buttons;
JLabel label, l;
public static int count;

public PanelJ2() {
setLayout( new GridLayout(5,5) );
setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 300, 200)); //I just wrote this line, I am not sure of the purpose quite really.
count = 0;
label = new JLabel("Number of guesses so far: " + count);
add(label);
l = new JLabel("");

buttons = new JButton[25];
for( int i = 0; i <= 24; i ++) {

  buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
  add(buttons[i]);
  buttons[i].addActionListener( new ExampleActionListener1());
}
setBackground( Color.green);
setVisible(false); //this is set true when the button "Start the freaking game is pressed"
}
}
```

Comment: The simple solution is to use a `CardLayout`.  Remove the `setPreferredSize` and let the layout managers deal with it...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/E1aLi9n.png
I just changed Grid to   setLayout( new CardLayout() ); in JPanel class, and removed setPreferredSize
It doesnt show the buttons now. Is there a different way to add componenets in a cardlayout?

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: you can also try using a windows builder to just drag and drop the required GUI. http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Comment: *"I have added the picture: `http://i.imgur..`"*  Please refrain from using swear words in posts, code samples *and* screen shots.  I was about to embed that image before I realized the title of the app.

Answer (score 1):

This `setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 7));` is going to cause the main issue.  A simpler issue would be to use a `CardLayout`

See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel2;

    private CardLayout cl;

    public MyJFrame() {
        cl = new CardLayout();
        setLayout(cl);
        panel2 = new PanelJ2();

        add(panel2, "LotsOfButtons");
        JButton b = new JButton("Start the freaking game");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(getContentPane(), "LotsOfButtons");
            }
        });
        add(b, "start");
        cl.show(getContentPane(), "start");
        setTitle("This is a freaking game");
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    static class PanelJ2 extends JPanel {

        JButton[] buttons;
        JLabel label, l;
        public static int count;

        public PanelJ2() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
//          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200)); //I just wrote this line, I am not sure of the purpose quite really.
            count = 0;
            label = new JLabel("Number of guesses so far: " + count);
            add(label);
            l = new JLabel("");

            buttons = new JButton[25];
            for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {

                buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
                add(buttons[i]);
//              buttons[i].addActionListener(new ExampleActionListener1());
            }
            setBackground(Color.green);
            setVisible(false); //this is set true when the button "Start the freaking game is pressed"
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                MyJFrame frame = new MyJFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You might want to put the button into a different container, maybe using a `GridBagLayout`

Comment: I fixed it using BorderLayout for both MyJFrame and PanelJ2 classes. Iis that unprofessional?

Moreover, your codes output is still not what I wanted however, would you mind explaining some parts of your code.
PanelJ2 object when constructed, the panel is setVisible(false); And you havent changed it to true anywhere else in the code. How does it gets true automatically when we press the Button b.
Secondly, is it more professional to write main method in last like you did, or in the beginning like I did. (our professor does like it)

Comment: *"Moreover, your codes output is still not what I wanted"* - Without an example of what you wanted, I made the best guess I could. *"PanelJ2 object when constructed, the panel is setVisible(false); And you havent changed it to true anywhere else in the code"* - I never call `setVisible(false)` on `panel2`, or any other component.  I use the `CardLayout` to switch the views, that's what it's designed for.

Comment: *"Secondly, is it more professional to write main method in last like you did, or in the beginning like I did. (our professor does like it)"* - That's a matter of opinion.  It tend to like putting it first as I can trace the start point from there, some people like putting it last because it gets in the way